# Probability and linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, vector-spaces, finite-fields

Hy , I would like to have some help on the following problem , if it is possible . Any contribution is welcom .

let $E$ a  $K$ vectoriel space of dimension $n\geq 1$ , and $K$ finite field of cardinal $q$ . 
Suppose that $L(E)$ is being provided by the uniform probability law . let $p_{n}(q)$ the probability of an endomorphism  being  a cyclic endomorphism ,  compute $ \lim_{q \to \infty} p_{n}(q)$ .

I am guessing the probability must be $1$ , I am  looking for a minoration .

Comment: If I correctly guessed what you mean by a cyclic endomorphism, then won't it be the case that a matrix with distinct eigenvalues (in the algebraic closure) is cyclic? That set is Zariski dense. Therefore it does seem likely that your guess is correct. If we restrict $q=p^t$, then may be Weil bounds (something looser may be enough?) imply that
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}p_n(p^t)=1.$$ I'm thinking about the variety defined by the resultant of the characteristic polynomial and its derivative. The positive cases containt the complement of that variety.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thank you  a lot sorry for my bad english , a cyclic endomorphism $u$ , is such that there is a vector $e$ ( that we  call cyclic vector ) such that $E=vect\{e,u(e) ,...,u^{n-1}(e)\}$  ,  it can be interesting , to find a minoration of the probability , for a given vector , to be a cyclic vector for a random endomorphism .